# Pandas: df.mul vs df.rmul

Tags: python, pandas

Can anybody help me understand the difference (if any) between the two methods: `df.mul` and `df.rmul`? The documentation looks identical:

[docs for mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)

[docs for rmul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rmul.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is not identical. As stated in the documentation, `df.mul(other)` is equivalent to `df * other`, while `df.rmul(other)` is equivalent to `other * df`.

This probably doesn't matter for most cases, but it will matter if, e.g., you have a dataframe of object dtype whose elements have noncommutative multiplication. Maybe you wrote a quaternion class and filled a dataframe with quaternions. Someone with more Pandas experience might be able to come up with more practical cases where it matters.

Answer (score 2):

From the code:

```
# not entirely sure why this is necessary, but previously was included
# so it's here to maintain compatibility
rmul=arith_method(operator.mul, names('rmul'), op('*'),
                  default_axis=default_axis, reversed=True),
```

Analogous lines for `mul`

```
mul=arith_method(operator.mul, names('mul'), op('*'),
                 default_axis=default_axis),
```

`rmul` has a flag `reversed=True`

My assumption is that the `reversed` flag is important for non commutative operations like subtraction and division.  It isn't necessary for multiplication, hence the comment.

For all practical purposes, it looks the same.